# Where, besides ntp.conf, do NTP servers used by ntpd come from?

Tags: time, ntp, ntpd

The only NTP servers I have defined in /etc/ntp.conf are as follows:

```
pool 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Yet when I check what's going on with NTP via `ntpq`, I see additional servers listed:

```
pi@clock:~ $ ntpq -pw
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
                 .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
 1.debian.pool.ntp.org
                 .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
 2.debian.pool.ntp.org
                 .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
                 .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
*SHM(2)          .PPS.            0 l   58   64  377    0.000    0.088   0.019
xSHM(0)          .GPS.            0 l   57   64  377    0.000  -453.88  28.633
+time.cloudflare.com
                 10.106.8.9       3 u   38   64  377   13.294    2.609   1.970
+time.cloudflare.com
                 10.106.8.9       3 u   20   64  377   12.476    2.657   2.750
-ntp1.wiktel.com .PPS.            1 u   23   64  377   54.800    1.160   3.709
-y.ns.gin.ntt.net
                 204.2.140.74     2 u   50  128  377   19.689    3.674   4.754
```

Where are these other NTP servers, such as `time.cloudflare.com` and `y.ns.gin.ntt.net`, configured and stored?

Comment: It appears that at least cloudflare participates in the pool: https://www.pool.ntp.org/scores/162.159.200.123.

Comment: So the listing of time.cloudflare.com, etc., perhaps just comes from doing reverse DNS on the reference identifier fields being returned by my configured servers?